# DefaultIfEmpty causing errors on Lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lambda

I have a rather simple lambda that needs to return a default value if the result set is empty.

```
         Trending blank = new Trending()
            {
                ID = 0,
                Username = "",
                NoteCount = 0,
                RecordDate = Convert.ToDateTime(StatDate),
                GroupID = 0
            };
            return _context.Trending
                .Where(x => x.Username == UserName && x.RecordDate == dt)
                .DefaultIfEmpty(blank)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

When I execute this, I get an invalidoperationException that the processing of .DefaultIfEmpty by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core.

Any suggestions as to what's wrong?  This is the first time I've had to use DefaultIfEmpty, but it should work.

Comment: is this gives the same error without `blank` parameter?

Comment: Why not just do `return _context.Trending.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == UserName && x.RecordDate == dt) ?? blank;`?

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!